# ng-chat Array con participantes

Tags: angular

Estoy montando un chat con ng-chat y estoy en el proceso de sacar las conversaciones activas del usuario. NG-Chat la demo viene con un array con unas conversaciones de DEMO, pero yo quiero mostrar mi array sacado de la base de datos.

```
    public static mockedParticipants: IChatParticipant[] = [
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 1,
        displayName: "Arya Stark",
        avatar: "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_9dd9bb497b75_128.pnj",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Online
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 2,
        displayName: "Cersei Lannister",
        avatar: null,
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Online
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 3,
        displayName: "Daenerys Targaryen",
        avatar: "https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_d28d7149f567_128.png",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Busy
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 4,
        displayName: "Eddard Stark",
        avatar: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/600707945911844864/MNogF757_400x400.jpg",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Offline
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 5,
        displayName: "Hodor",
        avatar: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000449071678/27f2e27edd119a7133110f8635f2c130.jpeg",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Offline
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 6,
        displayName: "Jaime Lannister",
        avatar: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000243930208/4fa8efadb63777ead29046d822606a57.jpeg",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Busy
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 7,
        displayName: "John Snow",
        avatar: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3456602315/aad436e6fab77ef4098c7a5b86cac8e3.jpeg",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Busy
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 8,
        displayName: "Lorde Petyr 'Littlefinger' Baelish",
        avatar: "http://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_ba75cbb26da7_128.png",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Offline
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 9,
        displayName: "Sansa Stark",
        avatar: "http://pm1.narvii.com/6201/dfe7ad75cd32130a5c844d58315cbca02fe5b804_128.jpg",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Online
    },
    {
        participantType: ChatParticipantType.User,
        id: 10,
        displayName: "Theon Greyjoy",
        avatar: "https://thumbnail.myheritageimages.com/502/323/78502323/000/000114_884889c3n33qfe004v5024_C_64x64C.jpg",
        status: ChatParticipantStatus.Away
    }
];
```

Este sería el Array DEMO, yo obtengo las conversaciones de la siguiente forma:

```
    getMessages() {
        this.profile.id = 184;
        this.chatService.getAllMessages(`?conversation_user=${this.profile.id}&limit=100`).subscribe(async (res: any) => {
        let msgs = await res.results;

        this.allMessages = [];
        })
     }
```

En this.allMessages tengo el array con las conversaciones pero ahí es donde me quedo, ya que no me deja hacer lo siguiente

```
public static mockedParticipants: IChatParticipant[] = this.allMessages;
```

Y finalmente tiene un observable

```
listFriends(): Observable<ParticipantResponse[]> {
    return of(DemoAdapter.mockedParticipants.map(user => {
    let participantResponse = new ParticipantResponse();

    participantResponse.participant = user;
    participantResponse.metadata = {
        totalUnreadMessages: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    }

    return participantResponse;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que tratas de asignar un array de mensajes a un array de participantes.

En la demo de `public static mockedParticipants: IChatParticipant[]`, la clase **`IChatParticipant`** es para **guardar los participantes** presentes en la sala de chat, que debe mantener esa estructura de campos del demo (puedes ver su clase en GitHub: https://github.com/rpaschoal/ng-chat/blob/master/src/ng-chat/core/chat-participant.ts), **pero tu estás intentando asignarle una lista de mensajes** (que imagino que tendrá objetos `Message`: https://github.com/rpaschoal/ng-chat/blob/master/src/ng-chat/core/message.ts).

Tendrás que cambiar y ahí asignarle los participantes.

Por cierto, ese observable que pones al final (el de saber el número de mensajes sin leer de los participantes), tiene un random para indicar el número de mesajes nuevos, no en base a datos reales. Te lo digo por si acaso.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás escribiendo la subscripción de esta manera funcione, ya que no estás asignando el valor. Suponiendo que la URL es correcta, claro.

```js
getMessages() {
  this.profile.id = 184;
  this.chatService.getAllMessages(`?conversation_user=${this.profile.id}&limit=100`).subscribe(messages => {
    if (messages) {
      this.allMessages = messages;
    }
  })
}
```